# Playing Some mp4 files from server cause me Exception

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I want to stream a video file from server to VideoView But it cause problem

```
videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideo);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://travel.gockell.com/data/251/videos/2016-06-09_13-21-12.mp4");

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```

Error

> D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
>                                                                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   http://travel.gockell.com/data/251/videos/2016-06-09_13-21-12.mp4
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1070)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:925)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:852)
>                                                                                                    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1094)
>                                                                                                    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:372)
>                                                                                                    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:73)
>                                                                                                    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:649)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:599)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:181)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192) 06-13
>   14:57:01.734
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>   06-13 14:57:01.764
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture 06-13 14:57:01.764
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3 06-13 14:57:01.764
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType 06-13 14:57:01.764
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: setVideoSurfaceTexture 06-13 14:57:01.764
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync 06-13 14:57:01.794
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val=
>   stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0.2) 06-13 14:57:01.874
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer I/Timeline:
>   Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@114c03a5
>   time:57014665 06-13 14:57:01.944
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: SBServiceAPI: getService class
>   android.os.ServiceManager 06-13 14:57:01.944
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 06-13
>   14:57:01.944
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true 06-13 14:57:01.944
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-40119-261283142: SmartBonding Enabling
>   is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false 06-13
>   14:57:01.944
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 06-13
>   14:57:03.314
>   16590-16605/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize is -1 06-13 14:57:03.324
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   D/MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeOut =  30000ms 06-13 14:57:05.814
>   16590-18648/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   D/MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeout with 30000ms 06-13 14:57:05.814
>   16590-18648/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 06-13
>   14:57:06.494
>   16590-18648/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize is -1 06-13 14:57:06.494
>   16590-18648/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaHTTPConnection: Server doesnt support Partial Request 06-13
>   14:57:06.494
>   16590-18648/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaHTTPConnection: Return -EPIPE 06-13 14:57:06.494
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
>   06-13 14:57:06.494
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648) 06-13 14:57:06.494
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: callback application 06-13 14:57:06.494
>   16590-16610/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   V/MediaPlayer: back from callback 06-13 14:57:06.504
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) 06-13 14:57:06.504
>   16590-16590/videoplayer.dreamdeveloper.com.livevideoplayer
>   D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: I think you have to look once on this [library](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle). And also check your [media](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) support file.

Comment: I want to play in default player is it possible ? @Lawrance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help every body all of code are fine no problem in code but problem was in emulator some time it plays and some time its not. Working on real device.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
String VideoURL = "http://travel.gockell.com/data/251/videos/2016-06-09_13-21-12.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);

videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

try {
    // Start the MediaController
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
    Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    videoview.setVideoURI(video);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            videoview.start();
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this one is working on me

```
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
try {
    // Start the MediaController
    final MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
            BioskopFilmDetail.this);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
    Uri video = Uri.parse(URLVIDEO );
    videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();                 
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });
    videoview.setVideoURI(video);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                
        videoview.start();
        //showInterstitialAd();
    }
});
```

dont forget add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in manifest